# storing data with the key in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the edit button or delete button of the row is clicked I want to store the student id along with the checked type i.e is either edit or delete type and later use it to update the data in the database. Currently I have written html and jquery to check the checkbox when the respective button is pressed. Now I am stuck in how to store the data in array and pass it forward. Data should be in the form like stdList(id = 1, check = 'edit').

Here is my html

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Checklist</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="editCheck" class="editCheck" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheck" class="deleteCheck" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control item" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control item" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control item" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="btn1">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="dbtn1">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="editCheck" class="btn2" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheck" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control item" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control item" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control item" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="btn2">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="dbtn2">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$('.btn.btn-info.btn-xs').click(function () {

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
    $tr.find('input:checkbox').first().prop('checked', 'true');

    $tr.find('input').removeAttr('readonly');
    check($tr);
});

$('.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs').click(function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.find('input:checkbox').last().prop('checked', 'true');
    check($tr);
});

function check($tr) {

    if (($tr.find('input:checkbox').first().is(":checked")) && ($tr.find('input:checkbox').last().is(":checked"))) {
        $('.alert.alert-danger').append('<p>You can not edit and update the field at once</p>');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the problem mentioned you need to save the student details and action invoked. So the below approach can be used to do the same.

> ```
> Create a object  like below .
>
> var item=new Object();
> item.studentId = "student id";
> item.Action="edit/delete action"
>
> Create an array to save this 
> var studentInfo = new Array();
>
> then Add items to array,
>
> studentInfo.push(item);
>
> Use the Array as required in you code
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First you can set the id in a data attribute on the table row `tr` element. Also add a value to the checkboxes which can be used in the array/object.

```
<tr data-id="1">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="editCheck" class="editCheck" value="edit" />
         <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheck" class="deleteCheck" value="delete" />
         ...
```

I simplified the `check` function a bit by counting the checked checkboxes (with `length`). With the value and the data attribute it's easy to create a JSON object which unlike arrays have key value pairs.

```
function check($tr) {
    var $checked = $tr.find('input:checked');
    var data = {};
    if ($checked.length > 1) {
        $('.alert.alert-danger').append('<p>You can not edit and update the field at once</p>');
        return false;
    }

    data.id = $tr.data('id');
    data.check = $checked.val();

    console.log(data); // Gives something like {id: 1, check: 'edit'}

}
```